# what if the key in kwargs has conflict with the function keyword

Tags: python, keyword-argument

in a function like

```
def myfunc(a, b, **kwargs):
    do someting
```

if the named parameters I've passed in has a keyword "a" already, the call will failed.

Currently I need to call myfunc with a dictionary from other place (so I can't control the content of the dictionary), like

```
myfunc(1,2, **dict)
```

how to make sure there is no conflict? if there is, what's the solution?

if there any way to write a decorator to solve this problem since this may be a common problem ?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls for an understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is seriously an issue, don't name your arguments. Just use splat arguments:

```
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

and parse `args` manually.

Comment: Another option is to obfuscate positional args into something really unlikely to be hit by chance, e.g. `def myfunc(__a, __b, **kwargs): ...`.

Answer (score 3):

If your function is taking a an actual dict from somewhere else, you don't need to pass it using `**`. Just pass the dict like a normal argument:

```
def myfunc(a, b, kwargs):
    # do something

myfunc(1,2, dct) # No ** needed
```

You only need to use `**kwargs` if `myfunc` is designed to take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments. Like this:

```
myfunc(1,2, a=3, b=5, something=5)
```

If you're just passing it a dict, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- if `myfunc(1,2, **otherdict)` is being called from some other place where you have no control over what's in `otherdict` - there's nothing you can do, they're calling your function incorrectly. The calling function needs to ensure no conflicts.
- if YOU are the calling function... then you just need to merge the dicts yourself. i.e.:

x

```
otherdict = some_called_function()`
# My values should take precedence over what's in the dict
otherdict.update(a=1, b=2)
# OR i am just supplying defaults in case they didn't
otherdict.setdefault('a', 1)
otherdict.setdefault('b', 2)
# In either case, then i just use kwargs only.
myfunc(**otherdict)
```